# Suspicious URL pattern in FilterRegistrationBean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, servlets

Recently I'm getting the following warning when starting my `spring-boot` application:

`o.a.c.c.StandardContext: Suspicious URL pattern: [/rest/**] in context [], see sections 12.1 and 12.2 of the Servlet specification`

Definition:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean traceFilterRegistration(HttpTraceFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/rest/**");
    return registration;
}
```

Question: is nowadays `/rest/*` the same as `/rest/**` so I could switch that safely?
My goal is obviously to catch any sub path under the rest path, eg also `/rest/this/is/my/sub`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specs for Servlet 3.1 and 4.0 state the following:

```
12.2 Specification of Mappings

In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define
mappings:
■ A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for
path mapping.
■ A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
■ The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
application's context root, i.e., requests of the form http://host:port/<contextroot>/. In this case the path info is ’/’ and the servlet path and context path is
empty string (““).
■ A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the
application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path
and the path info is null.
■ All other strings are used for exact matches only.
If the effective web.xml (after merging information from fragments and
annotations) contains any
```

Which means the pattern `/rest/**` is an invalid one and should be changed to `/rest/*`.